# I need to loop trhough the descriptions on a JSON object, how to find the index?

Tags: javascript, json

Below please find the JSON response.
What I need is to get all "descriptions" returned in that JSON response object.
To loop through and get the descriptions I need a way to get the index of, in my case, of the "textAnnotations".

In the following JSON 4 "textAnnotations" have been returned, How do I get this 4?

What I need is to get:

```
payload.responses[0].textAnnotations[0].description
payload.responses[0].textAnnotations[1].description
payload.responses[0].textAnnotations[2].description
payload.responses[0].textAnnotations[3].description

{
  "responses": [
    {
      "textAnnotations": [
        {
          "locale": "en",
          "description": "BR\nCOUNTRY\nERD6100",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 61,
                "y": 247
              },
              {
                "x": 461,
                "y": 247
              },
              {
                "x": 461,
                "y": 359
              },
              {
                "x": 61,
                "y": 359
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "description": "BR",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 62,
                "y": 339
              },
              {
                "x": 86,
                "y": 340
              },
              {
                "x": 85,
                "y": 359
              },
              {
                "x": 61,
                "y": 358
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "description": "COUNTRY",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 253,
                "y": 249
              },
              {
                "x": 323,
                "y": 250
              },
              {
                "x": 323,
                "y": 264
              },
              {
                "x": 253,
                "y": 263
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "description": "ERD6100",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 95,
                "y": 277
              },
              {
                "x": 461,
                "y": 281
              },
              {
                "x": 460,
                "y": 352
              },
              {
                "x": 94,
                "y": 348
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "fullTextAnnotation": {
        "pages": [
          {
            "property": {
              "detectedLanguages": [
                {
                  "languageCode": "en",
                  "confidence": 0.4885855
                },
                {
                  "languageCode": "pt",
                  "confidence": 0.38148627
                }
              ]
            },
            "width": 800,
            "height": 600,
            "blocks": [
              {
                "boundingBox": {
                  "vertices": [
                    {
                      "x": 62,
                      "y": 339
                    },
                    {
                      "x": 86,
                      "y": 340
                    },
                    {
                      "x": 85,
                      "y": 359
                    },
                    {
                      "x": 61,
                      "y": 358
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "paragraphs": [
                  {
                    "boundingBox": {
                      "vertices": [
                        {
                          "x": 62,
                          "y": 339
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 86,
                          "y": 340
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 85,
                          "y": 359
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 61,
                          "y": 358
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "words": [
                      {
                        "boundingBox": {
                          "vertices": [
                            {
                              "x": 62,
                              "y": 339
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 86,
                              "y": 340
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 85,
                              "y": 359
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 61,
                              "y": 358
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "symbols": [
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 62,
                                  "y": 339
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 76,
                                  "y": 339
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 75,
                                  "y": 358
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 61,
                                  "y": 358
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "B"
                          },
                          {
                            "property": {
                              "detectedBreak": {
                                "type": "LINE_BREAK"
                              }
                            },
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 74,
                                  "y": 339
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 86,
                                  "y": 339
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 85,
                                  "y": 358
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 73,
                                  "y": 358
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "R"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "blockType": "TEXT"
              },
              {
                "boundingBox": {
                  "vertices": [
                    {
                      "x": 95,
                      "y": 247
                    },
                    {
                      "x": 461,
                      "y": 251
                    },
                    {
                      "x": 460,
                      "y": 352
                    },
                    {
                      "x": 94,
                      "y": 348
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "paragraphs": [
                  {
                    "boundingBox": {
                      "vertices": [
                        {
                          "x": 253,
                          "y": 249
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 323,
                          "y": 250
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 323,
                          "y": 264
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 253,
                          "y": 263
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "words": [
                      {
                        "property": {
                          "detectedLanguages": [
                            {
                              "languageCode": "pt",
                              "confidence": 1
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "boundingBox": {
                          "vertices": [
                            {
                              "x": 253,
                              "y": 249
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 323,
                              "y": 250
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 323,
                              "y": 264
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 253,
                              "y": 263
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "symbols": [
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 253,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 264,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 264,
                                  "y": 263
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 253,
                                  "y": 263
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "B"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 265,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 277,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 277,
                                  "y": 263
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 265,
                                  "y": 263
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "R"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 279,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 292,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 292,
                                  "y": 263
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 279,
                                  "y": 263
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "A"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 294,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 303,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 303,
                                  "y": 263
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 294,
                                  "y": 263
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "S"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 306,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 313,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 313,
                                  "y": 263
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 306,
                                  "y": 263
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "I"
                          },
                          {
                            "property": {
                              "detectedBreak": {
                                "type": "LINE_BREAK"
                              }
                            },
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 313,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 323,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 323,
                                  "y": 263
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 313,
                                  "y": 263
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "L"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "boundingBox": {
                      "vertices": [
                        {
                          "x": 95,
                          "y": 277
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 461,
                          "y": 281
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 460,
                          "y": 352
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 94,
                          "y": 348
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "words": [
                      {
                        "property": {
                          "detectedLanguages": [
                            {
                              "languageCode": "en",
                              "confidence": 1
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "boundingBox": {
                          "vertices": [
                            {
                              "x": 95,
                              "y": 277
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 461,
                              "y": 281
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 460,
                              "y": 352
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 94,
                              "y": 348
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "symbols": [
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 95,
                                  "y": 278
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 142,
                                  "y": 279
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 141,
                                  "y": 349
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 94,
                                  "y": 348
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "E"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 149,
                                  "y": 278
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 198,
                                  "y": 279
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 197,
                                  "y": 349
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 148,
                                  "y": 348
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "R"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 202,
                                  "y": 279
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 248,
                                  "y": 280
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 247,
                                  "y": 350
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 201,
                                  "y": 349
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "D"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 260,
                                  "y": 279
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 299,
                                  "y": 279
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 298,
                                  "y": 349
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 259,
                                  "y": 349
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "6"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 314,
                                  "y": 280
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 352,
                                  "y": 280
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 351,
                                  "y": 350
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 313,
                                  "y": 350
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "1"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 366,
                                  "y": 281
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 407,
                                  "y": 281
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 406,
                                  "y": 351
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 365,
                                  "y": 351
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "0"
                          },
                          {
                            "property": {
                              "detectedBreak": {
                                "type": "LINE_BREAK"
                              }
                            },
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 420,
                                  "y": 281
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 461,
                                  "y": 281
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 460,
                                  "y": 351
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 419,
                                  "y": 351
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "0"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "blockType": "TEXT"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "text": "BR\nCOUNTRY\nERD6100"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Assistance welcome.
Paulo

Comment: Are you just asking how to loop over an array?  `for (let x = 0; x < payload.responses[0].textAnnotations.length; x++)` ?

Comment: Dear David, that was precisely what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this to extract the descriptions

```js
const getDescriptions = data => 
  data.flatMap(d => d.textAnnotations? 
                    d.textAnnotations.map(t => t.description): 
                    []
              )


const data = {
  "responses": [
    {
      "textAnnotations": [
        {
          "locale": "en",
          "description": "BR\nCOUNTRY\nERD6100",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 61,
                "y": 247
              },
              {
                "x": 461,
                "y": 247
              },
              {
                "x": 461,
                "y": 359
              },
              {
                "x": 61,
                "y": 359
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "description": "BR",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 62,
                "y": 339
              },
              {
                "x": 86,
                "y": 340
              },
              {
                "x": 85,
                "y": 359
              },
              {
                "x": 61,
                "y": 358
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "description": "COUNTRY",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 253,
                "y": 249
              },
              {
                "x": 323,
                "y": 250
              },
              {
                "x": 323,
                "y": 264
              },
              {
                "x": 253,
                "y": 263
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "description": "ERD6100",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 95,
                "y": 277
              },
              {
                "x": 461,
                "y": 281
              },
              {
                "x": 460,
                "y": 352
              },
              {
                "x": 94,
                "y": 348
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "fullTextAnnotation": {
        "pages": [
          {
            "property": {
              "detectedLanguages": [
                {
                  "languageCode": "en",
                  "confidence": 0.4885855
                },
                {
                  "languageCode": "pt",
                  "confidence": 0.38148627
                }
              ]
            },
            "width": 800,
            "height": 600,
            "blocks": [
              {
                "boundingBox": {
                  "vertices": [
                    {
                      "x": 62,
                      "y": 339
                    },
                    {
                      "x": 86,
                      "y": 340
                    },
                    {
                      "x": 85,
                      "y": 359
                    },
                    {
                      "x": 61,
                      "y": 358
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "paragraphs": [
                  {
                    "boundingBox": {
                      "vertices": [
                        {
                          "x": 62,
                          "y": 339
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 86,
                          "y": 340
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 85,
                          "y": 359
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 61,
                          "y": 358
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "words": [
                      {
                        "boundingBox": {
                          "vertices": [
                            {
                              "x": 62,
                              "y": 339
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 86,
                              "y": 340
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 85,
                              "y": 359
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 61,
                              "y": 358
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "symbols": [
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 62,
                                  "y": 339
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 76,
                                  "y": 339
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 75,
                                  "y": 358
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 61,
                                  "y": 358
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "B"
                          },
                          {
                            "property": {
                              "detectedBreak": {
                                "type": "LINE_BREAK"
                              }
                            },
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 74,
                                  "y": 339
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 86,
                                  "y": 339
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 85,
                                  "y": 358
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 73,
                                  "y": 358
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "R"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "blockType": "TEXT"
              },
              {
                "boundingBox": {
                  "vertices": [
                    {
                      "x": 95,
                      "y": 247
                    },
                    {
                      "x": 461,
                      "y": 251
                    },
                    {
                      "x": 460,
                      "y": 352
                    },
                    {
                      "x": 94,
                      "y": 348
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "paragraphs": [
                  {
                    "boundingBox": {
                      "vertices": [
                        {
                          "x": 253,
                          "y": 249
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 323,
                          "y": 250
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 323,
                          "y": 264
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 253,
                          "y": 263
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "words": [
                      {
                        "property": {
                          "detectedLanguages": [
                            {
                              "languageCode": "pt",
                              "confidence": 1
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "boundingBox": {
                          "vertices": [
                            {
                              "x": 253,
                              "y": 249
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 323,
                              "y": 250
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 323,
                              "y": 264
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 253,
                              "y": 263
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "symbols": [
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 253,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 264,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 264,
                                  "y": 263
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 253,
                                  "y": 263
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "B"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 265,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 277,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 277,
                                  "y": 263
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 265,
                                  "y": 263
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "R"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 279,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 292,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 292,
                                  "y": 263
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 279,
                                  "y": 263
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "A"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 294,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 303,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 303,
                                  "y": 263
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 294,
                                  "y": 263
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "S"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 306,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 313,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 313,
                                  "y": 263
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 306,
                                  "y": 263
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "I"
                          },
                          {
                            "property": {
                              "detectedBreak": {
                                "type": "LINE_BREAK"
                              }
                            },
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 313,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 323,
                                  "y": 250
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 323,
                                  "y": 263
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 313,
                                  "y": 263
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "L"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "boundingBox": {
                      "vertices": [
                        {
                          "x": 95,
                          "y": 277
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 461,
                          "y": 281
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 460,
                          "y": 352
                        },
                        {
                          "x": 94,
                          "y": 348
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "words": [
                      {
                        "property": {
                          "detectedLanguages": [
                            {
                              "languageCode": "en",
                              "confidence": 1
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "boundingBox": {
                          "vertices": [
                            {
                              "x": 95,
                              "y": 277
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 461,
                              "y": 281
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 460,
                              "y": 352
                            },
                            {
                              "x": 94,
                              "y": 348
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "symbols": [
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 95,
                                  "y": 278
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 142,
                                  "y": 279
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 141,
                                  "y": 349
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 94,
                                  "y": 348
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "E"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 149,
                                  "y": 278
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 198,
                                  "y": 279
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 197,
                                  "y": 349
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 148,
                                  "y": 348
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "R"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 202,
                                  "y": 279
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 248,
                                  "y": 280
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 247,
                                  "y": 350
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 201,
                                  "y": 349
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "D"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 260,
                                  "y": 279
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 299,
                                  "y": 279
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 298,
                                  "y": 349
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 259,
                                  "y": 349
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "6"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 314,
                                  "y": 280
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 352,
                                  "y": 280
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 351,
                                  "y": 350
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 313,
                                  "y": 350
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "1"
                          },
                          {
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 366,
                                  "y": 281
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 407,
                                  "y": 281
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 406,
                                  "y": 351
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 365,
                                  "y": 351
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "0"
                          },
                          {
                            "property": {
                              "detectedBreak": {
                                "type": "LINE_BREAK"
                              }
                            },
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [
                                {
                                  "x": 420,
                                  "y": 281
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 461,
                                  "y": 281
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 460,
                                  "y": 351
                                },
                                {
                                  "x": 419,
                                  "y": 351
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "text": "0"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "blockType": "TEXT"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "text": "BR\nCOUNTRY\nERD6100"
      }
    }
  ]
}

console.log(getDescriptions(data.responses))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to loop through the array as follows:

```
payload.responses[0].textAnnotations.map((textAnn, index) => {
   return textAnn.description
})
```

You can either return or push desired value to array.